# Python Pandas: Input numeric value on string message

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I want to input the computed numeric value on my MESSAGE variable. So basically I computed first my numeric value and then put it on a message string. Below is my code.

```
#Compute numeric value
LOCATIONS_COUNT = len(loc_df)
#Add the computed numeric value to the message
MESSAGE = "The total locations is LOCATION_COUNT"
print(MESSAGE)
#This was the result
The total locations is LOCATION_COUNT
```

Basically I need the result to output the numeric value for LOCATION_COUNT. For example the value is 10. Then the MESSAGE should be like this.

```
The total locations is 10
```

Comment: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: If you are > 3.6 use format string literal: `f'The total locations is {LOCATION_COUNT}.'`

Comment: Yes I'm using 3.8. I'm having error with this MESSAGE = f"The total locations is {LOCATION_COUNT}"

Comment: @Bustergun what is your error?

Comment: python won't allow the {LOCATION_COUNT} part

Comment: Got it already. Sorry I just used {LOCATIONS_COUNT} on my code. It should be just {LOCATION_COUNT}. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. You could cast your int to string:

```
#Add the computed numeric value to the message
MESSAGE = "The total locations is "+ str(LOCATION_COUNT)
print(MESSAGE)
```

Or use some sort of string formatting, like this:

```
#Compute numeric value
LOCATION_COUNT = len(loc_df)
#Add the computed numeric value to the message
MESSAGE = f'The total locations is {LOCATION_COUNT}'
print(MESSAGE)
```

Or this:

```
#Compute numeric value
LOCATION_COUNT = len(loc_df)
#Add the computed numeric value to the message
MESSAGE = "The total locations is "
print("{}{}".format(MESSAGE, LOCATION_COUNT))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Format** :

```
LOCATIONS_COUNT = len(loc_df)
MESSAGE = "The total locations is {}".format(LOCATIONS_COUNT)
print(MESSAGE)
```

**or**

```
MESSAGE = "The total locations is {}".format(len(loc_df))
print(MESSAGE)
```